# RestTemplate, Spring boot , POST

Tags: java, spring, post

I have a rest api at localhost:8086/addMessage and it works when I test it using POSTMAN. But when I want to integrate this API on client side it returns:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 10: localhost:
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848) ~[na:1.8.0_171]  error:
```

This is my method that calls API:

```
  public void addOrder(Message orders) throws  Exception
    {  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
      String resp = restTemplate.postForObject(
                "localhost:8086/addMessage",
                orders,
                String.class);    
    }
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 30):

Add 'http' scheme to your url,

> http://localhost:8086/addMessage

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using localhost then pass url like this-
http://localhost:8080/api/notes
 defining scheme is important (http/https)
do not use space also.
For Your Question answer should be-
http://localhost:8086/addMessage

Answer (score 0):

Adding  **http://** or **https://** scheme to URL has worked for me

```
restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8086/addMessage", orders, String.class);
```

or

```
restTemplate.postForObject("https://localhost:8086/addMessage", orders, String.class);
```

Thanks @stacker and @Shubham